# finding series of polynomials converging to $f(x)=x$

Tags: polynomials, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I want to find a series of polynomials with even powers $P_n : [0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ such that is uniformly converging to the function $f(x)=x$.

I got a hint that says to first find a series $Q_n(x)$ that converges to $g(x)=\sqrt x$ and then set $P_n(x)=Q_n(x^2)$

I tried using fourier series but i got stuck when I was trying to solve the integral
$$\hat g (n)= \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_0^1 \sqrt x e^{-inx}$$
since this integral doesn't have a solution.

Comment: Why Fourier series? I would rather suggest Taylor expansion

Comment: Do the Taylor series about $1$, not $0$.